# What does this incorrect (yet valid) SQL join even mean? What is it actually doing?

Tags: sql, join, syntax, interpreter

Consider the following SQL statement

```
select * 
from A
    inner join B on A.FK = B.PK
    inner join C on A.FK = B.PK
```

This is clearly an incorrectly formed statement. The join of C is using the join conditions for B. However, this still runs. How does the interpreter decide to join C in this situation? Why is this even an allowed statement? Are there ever any situations where something like this is desirable?

Comment: Is it returning `correct` data ? To me, it looks like developer did a typographical error and never re-validated the output.

Comment: @Amit - this isn't a question about a specific situation. I thought of this question because I did in fact make a copy paste error with something I am working on and corrected it. However, I noticed that the SQL statement still ran (for a long time) and I killed it. The question is "What what it actually doing, why is it allowed, and is it ever desirable?".

Comment: Optimizer is free to rearragne conditions at will. So this will be equivalent to when both conditions (one really) are in the WHERE section. As to "what it is doing" - cartesian product is what it's doing.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - so you are saying that the entire table C would be joined for every row of AB? That would explain why it ran for so long.

Comment: @ChechyLevas: yep, that's exactly what would happen.

Comment: With JOINs, your statement is syntactically correct to be allowed for logical query processing and data fetch from SQL data pages. What it is going to return, is incorrect data.

Comment: For this example, it will simply create duplicated result (multiplied by number of rows in table C) because of the "wrong" join on C. It's developer's responsibility to get the logic right, the interpreter doesn't care much. There may be some scenarios where something like this is desirable, but I can't think of any right now.

Comment: @Amit- it seems to me that it would be a useful part of the syntax rules to force all joins of table X, to have a condition related to table X.

Comment: @ChechyLevas May be, but you can think this way too. Right now, this query would return complete result set of JOIN condition between A table and B table (which may be, say 5 rows), duplicated for each row in C table. This may be undesireable result set 99.9% of the time, but you have in-built categorization in this case. To `force all joins of table X, to have a condition related to table X.` is really upto SQL implementation teams for products. But good suggestion though.

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5e552/1/0

Answer (score 1):

The join condition from a to b is just duplicated, it doesn't matter where it is in the sql as long as after on word. I believe this to be the case.

You are doing a catersian join to the outcome of the join a to b here. If a and b join to produce 15 rows, and c has 20 then your result set is 300 rows.